# Can I avoid the native fullscreen video player with HTML5 on iPhone or android?

Tags: iphone, android, html, video, fullscreen

I've built a web app that uses the HTML5  tag and JavaScript code that renders other content synchronized with the running video. It works great in desktop browsers: Firefox, Chrome, and Safari. On an iPhone or a DroidX, the native video player pops up and takes over the screen, thus obscuring the other dynamic content that I want to display simultaneously with the video.

Is there any way around this? If necessary, I'll figure out how to write native apps for both those platforms, but it would save me a ton of effort if I could just stick with HTML5/JavaScript.

Comment: Actually, browser implementations of a/v players in both ios and android are buggy like hell. Try several players on the page or try to add stylish controls to them and you will see - its unusable. So, probably external fullscreen app for playing video - isn't so bad ;)

Comment: I am happy every time apple devices renders my content in the intended way. I use to celebrate that.

Comment: Technically no, but there are a couple libraries available that **make it possible,** like [iphone-inline-video](https://github.com/bfred-it/iphone-inline-video) (disclosure: I wrote it)

Answer (score 97):

## In iOS 10+

Apple enabled the attribute `playsinline` in all browsers on iOS 10, so this works seamlessly:

```
<video src="file.mp4" playsinline>
```

## In iOS 8 and iOS 9

**Short answer:** use [iphone-inline-video](https://github.com/bfred-it/iphone-inline-video), it enables inline playback and syncs the audio.

**Long answer:** You can work around this issue by simulating the playback by *skimming* the video instead of actually `.play()`'ing it.

Comment: It does not work in the Captive Network Assistant (Captive Portal)

Comment: Even in 2023 this rescued me, thank you!  My issue was with recording inline so I was focused on searching for inline options to the the MediaRecorder object, but this was all I needed.

Answer (score 59):

There's a property that enables/disables in line media playback in the iOS web browser (if you were writing a native app, it would be the `allowsInlineMediaPlayback` property of a UIWebView). By default on iPhone this is set to `NO`, but on iPad it's set to `YES`.

Fortunately for you, you can also adjust this behaviour in HTML as follows:

`<video id="myVideo" width="280" height="140" webkit-playsinline>`

...that should hopefully sort it out for you. I don't know if it will work on your Android devices. It's a webkit property, so it might. Worth a go, anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, it didn't change the behavior I'm seeing - full-screen native video players pop up on both iPhone and DroidX.

Comment: I am having this issue too.  I have added the webkit-playsinline and even the xml validated version of webkit-playsinline="webkit-playsinline", but doesn't change the behavior

Comment: This may not work in Safari for iPhone since the web view does not allow inline video playback. If however, the webpage is hosted within your own UIWebView within your own app, you can set these properties and inline video playback will be possible:

webview.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
webview.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;

Comment: I've read that this works only within UIWebView in native apps AND in web pages ONLY when you save them to the home screen as webapps.

Comment: This works in Cordova/PhoneGap, too. Just add the following to your config.xml in Cordova project: `<preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true" />`

Comment: <preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true" />
Great!.
it works fine on my iPhone. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks @Mr.TA. You save my time.

Answer (score 44):

**Old answer (applicable till 2016)**

Here's an Apple developer link that **explicitly** says that -

*on iPhone and iPod touch, which are small screen devices, "Video is **NOT** presented within the Web Page"*

[**Safari Device-Specific Considerations**](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html)

**Your options**:

- The `webkit-playsinline` attribute works for HTML5 videos on iOS but **only when you save the webpage to your home screen as a webapp** - Not if opened a page in Safari
- For a native app with a WebView (or a hybrid app with HTML, CSS, JS) the `UIWebView` allows to play the video inline, but only if you [set the `allowsInlineMediaPlayback` property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWebView/allowsInlineMediaPlayback) for the **`UIWebView`** class to true

Comment: See my comments to the accepted answer. ICYMI, for Cordova, add the following to your config.xml: `<preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true" />`

Comment: On YouTube.com it plays without without going fullscreen

Comment: The answer is old, 2014, and things may have changed. Also, youtube.com is not a ***native app with a WebView*** as mentioned in the answer. Thanks for noticing though.

Answer (score 20):

In iOS 10 beta 4.The right code in HTML5 is

```
<video src="file.mp4" webkit-playsinline="true" playsinline="true">
```

`webkit-playsinline` is for iOS < 10, and `playsinline` is for iOS >= 10

See details via https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/

Answer (score 11):

According to this page 
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/Attributes.html
it is only available if (Enabled only in a UIWebView with the allowsInlineMediaPlayback property set to YES.) I understand in Mobile Safari this is YES on iPad and NO on iPhone and iPod Touch.

Comment: It seems like this would only work if you were setting up an HTML5 player page to "live within" a native iOS app. It certainly doesn't work on a plain ol' webpage.

Answer (score 9):

I don't know about android, but Safari on the iPhone or iPod touch will play all videos full screen because of the small screen size. On the iPad it will play the video on the page but allow the user to make it full screen.

Answer (score 1):

For React.js ,don't forget to use camelcase :

```
<video src="file.mp4" playsInline>
```