# Movie "inline" in Safari on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, mobile-safari

Is there a way to play a movie "inline" in Safari on iPhone, just like on an iPad or a desktop computer?

When exporting a movie with Quicktime "Save for the web..." feature, or when referencing a movie with an HTML5  tag, the movies keep on being zoomed to fullscreen when being run.

Screen is small, sure, and this is certainly the reason why it has been done this way, but I wish there was a way to override that.

Thanks.

Comment: I just saw this thread which apparently confirms this is not possible... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054560/can-i-avoid-the-native-fullscreen-video-player-with-html5-on-iphone-or-android. Never mind!