# Video Tag on iPhone - Auto Fullscreen

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, html5-video

When I play a video on iphons safari automatically go on full screen mode.
Can you detect it with a javaScript Event?

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054560/can-i-avoid-the-native-fullscreen-video-player-with-html5-on-iphone-or-android)

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)aWebView 
{
    [webView sizeToFit];

}
```