# "webkit-playsinline" video tag attribute

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, fullscreen

The `<video>` tag attribute `webkit-playsinline` supposedly prevents the default go to fullscreen behavior of HTML5 videos.

I added this attribute to my video tag and checked mobile safari and chrome on iOS6 iPhone and it doesn't work. The video still goes fullscreen. [This is similar to others' experiences as described on SO two years ago.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054560/can-i-avoid-the-native-fullscreen-video-player-with-html5-on-iphone-or-android)

What mobile browsers as of today, June 13th, 2013 does this attribute `webkit-playsinline` work?

Comment: Seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054560/can-i-avoid-the-native-fullscreen-video-player-with-html5-on-iphone-or-android

Comment: @Zenith thanks, yes but that Q&A is over 2 years old. Was wondering on people's experiences since this time. I will add the link to the question though.

Comment: No worries, but everywhere I've seen it used have involved both a native iOS app and HTML5 unfortunately..

Comment: @Zenith yeah UIWebView still seems to be only place this works.

Answer (score 42):

Apple has finally enabled the `playsinline` attribute on iOS 10, so this will work:

```
<video src="file.mp4" playsinline>
```

I wrote a polyfill called [iphone-inline-video](https://github.com/bfred-it/iphone-inline-video) that adds the same behavior to iOS 8 and 9.

Comment: In React, this is `playsInline`, similar to other attributes.

Answer (score 17):

The `webkit-playsinline` attribute works for HTML5 video on iOS4+ but only when you save the webpage to your home screen as a webapp. If you are using mobile Safari it will always open fullscreen.

Theres a small blurb about its support here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

I've also seen on recent versions of Android that inline video playback does work within its native browser.

Comment: -@blacktooth, can you mention specific versions of Android that you found it to work?

Comment: How do we save it as a web app on an iPhone ?

Comment: @ihue: Save the URL to homescreen and start it from there. However, webkit-playsinline doesn't work then either as far as I can say.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like this [might finally get implemented properly in iOS 10](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_10_0.html)

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me. I tried to use `playsinline` inside of video tag. But it didn't work so I tried to set attribute from `jQuery`

```
$('#you video tag id').attr('playsinline','');
```