# Webkit-playsinline on iphone

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, html, video

I'm currently working on a project with a lot of videos and this project needs to work on iphone.

But actually, the ios's video placeholder doesn't allows me to scroll in my page. I try to apply the webkit-playsinline attribute on my video tag but it doesn't work.

Is there a way - in full HTML5/JS - to prevent the native behavior of ios video player ?

I note that this problem is only on iphone (ios 7), not ipad.

Thanks !

Here my video tag :

```
<video vineresizer preload="auto" poster="{{vine.src_poster}}" loop webkit-playsinline="webkit-playsinline" controls="controls">
    <source ng-src="{{ trustSrc(vine.src_video) }}" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

And my js :

```
var video = element[0];
video.addEventListener('contextmenu', function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation(); }, 
false);

if (video.hasAttribute('controls')) {
    video.removeAttribute('controls');
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've been looking into this issue extensively as well.

Unfortunately, 'webkit-playsinline' only works in a UIWebView in a native app, and then only when a flag is set in the native code.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17090906/webkit-playsinline-video-tag-attribute) question.

From Apple's docs it seems there is no way to prevent this default behavior, but you can still capture the 'ended' and 'paused' events from the native player as if it were simply an HTML5 player inline in the page.  I.e. event listeners on 'ended' etc. should still work.

You can also get some state information from the native player: https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Reference/HTMLVideoElementClassReference/HTMLVideoElement/HTMLVideoElement.html

Overall, you can only interact with the native player in a very limited way, and no known overrides exist.

Answer (score 2):

## In iOS 10+

Apple will finally enable the attribute `playsinline` in all browsers on iOS 10, so this will work seamlessly:

```
<video src="file.mp4" playsinline>
```

## In iOS 8 and iOS 9

You can reproduce the behavior by simulating the playback by *skimming* the video instead of actually `.play()`'ing it.

[iphone-inline-video](https://github.com/bfred-it/iphone-inline-video) can take care of the playback and audio sync (if any), and it keeps the `<video>` working as it should.

Comment: Actually, the attribute's name in the latest ios10 betas is `<video src="file.mp4" playsinline>`

Comment: Is there a way to force YouTube videos to "playsinline"?