# How to use iOS playsinline with Javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, jquery-animate, adobe, createjs

I am trying to figure out how to make a video play inside the webpage and not open the iOS native player. I am creating the page in Adobe Animate HTML5 canvas. I understand that I want to use playsinline but I know very little about code and am having trouble implementing it. My understanding that this is possible is based on this website:

https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/

I have been working on this for days and Adobe's forums haven't been able to help. I even tried publishing the .html/.js files and then opening them in dreamweaver and looking for places to add the playsinline code manually but nothing seems to work.
I've also read through these forum posts but I don't really understand them:
[use webkit-playsinline in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472690/use-webkit-playsinline-in-javascript)

[HTML5 inline video on iPhone vs iPad/Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699552/html5-inline-video-on-iphone-vs-ipad-browser)

[Webkit-playsinline on iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697311/webkit-playsinline-on-iphone)

["webkit-playsinline" video tag attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17090906/webkit-playsinline-video-tag-attribute)

Here is the relevant code from Frame 1 of my Adobe Animate file. I am just wondering where to paste the playsinline code, or if I have to do it another way:

```
this.stop();

var nextBtnVAR = this.nextBtn;
var timelineVAR = this;


this.playBtn.addEventListener("click", playVideoFUNC.bind(this));
        function playVideoFUNC()
        {
        $("#video1")[0].src = "videos/2.mp4";
        $("#video1")[0].play();
        this.pauseBtn.visible = true;
        }

this.pauseBtn.addEventListener("click", pauseVideoFUNC.bind(this));
        function pauseVideoFUNC()
        {
        $("#video1")[0].pause();
        this.pauseBtn.visible = false;
        }

this.nextBtn.addEventListener("click", nextFrameFUNC.bind(this));
        function nextFrameFUNC()
        {
        this.gotoAndStop(2);
        }       


this.video1.on("added", function()
{
$("#video1")[0].addEventListener('ended', timelineVAR.endedHandler);
}
);

this.endedHandler = function(e)
{
timelineVAR.gotoAndStop(1);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

i have found an example for donwload here: https://dizply.com/responsive-in-banner-video-ad-with-adobe-animate-cc/
they did it like this:

```
var video = document.createElement('video');
video.setAttribute('playsinline', 'playsinline');
```