# Best method to display html5 video on IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, html

I'm breaking my head for few days trying to solve this and can't seems to find answer.

I'm trying to build a proof of concept for video player using HTML5 that works on Android and IOS, the trick is that at certain times i need to display objects on the video itself.

Now i would normally use the Video on Canvas or Video tag to solve it and then just create a layer on that with whatever additional data i want synced and triggered by the timer (on my specific example i've used PopcornJS to trigger time-based events).

NOW, it works fine on normal desktop browsers and it works well enough for android
but it seems that Safari won't render it no matter what... it insist on opening the video in it's own player that disregard any additional JS/HTML.

Ref about the issue [can be seen here](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: Do you have any example code? Also on iOS all videos (certainly from web pages) will open in a full screen player.

Comment: I don't have a code sample but any sample will do, for example: <video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video> and yes, it does open in full screen player (native, with no DOM/html5/js support..  that's the issue.. i'm trying to overlay the video with a custom message and the player just shows the video itself and will skip the code.

Answer (score 0):

Afraid it isn't currently possible on iPhone in Safari. I've been working on an interactive presentation web app and have encountered the same problem.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054560/can-i-avoid-the-native-fullscreen-video-player-with-html5-on-iphone-or-android) covers the problem of full screen only video on the iPhone. The answers mention the [webkit-playsinline](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/Attributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008058-SW30) attribute but point out that it only works inside a `UIWebView` object, not in Safari.

Hopefully this will change at some point in the future.

Comment: I've actually ended up going with Sprite (convert the movie into strip of photos and drawing them individually on a canvas) it works well enough *but* it's limited to Safari's max image size.