# Can we avoid the native player in Full screen with Html 5 Player

Tags: ios, iphone, html, uiwebview, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am trying to implement a html 5 player inside a Webview in my app. I added the **webkit-playsinline** tab in video and its now playing inline in iPhone and iPad.

The issue arises is when user hits the fullscreen button, in both the iphone and iPad, it opens up the native player, which I don't want.

Can this be achieved?

I have followed this and thats why I am able to play the video inline however, when the user click on the "Full Screen" the control transfer to the native player which I don't want.

yes, I am using a UIWebView inside my app not safari specific!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I avoid the native fullscreen video player with HTML5 on iPhone or android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054560/can-i-avoid-the-native-fullscreen-video-player-with-html5-on-iphone-or-android)

Comment: (note that the second answer in that duplicate is the most relevant; specifically "... only when you save the webpage to your home screen as a webapp". For standard web pages, it looks like this part of the UI is required)