# Can I avoid the native fullscreen video player in Jwplayer on iPhone

Tags: iphone, html, video, fullscreen, jwplayer

I came across this [ans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36348909/1877909) to avoid fullscreen video player in iPhone.Can we use this module to create video player custom controls.

I have using jwplayer and have own custom video controls (fast forward/backward, transcript, slow/fast, volume control, fullscreen).This controls gets hidden in iPhone and native iPhone video player is shown.

Is there any way to avoid this iphone fullscreen and still bring own custom controls.

Can this [module](https://github.com/bfred-it/iphone-inline-video) be used for jwplayer? to bring own custom video control with jwplayer.

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen that particular library in use with our player, so you're more than able to try it - but I cannot guarantee any success, nor can we provide support for its use.

With that being said, iOS 10 is slated to bring inline video playback to Safari for iPhone and the good news is our player is already set up in the way it needs to take advantage of this. Obviously, iOS 10 is in beta and not final yet so things are subject to change, but this is good news for those customers looking for inline video playback in Safari on iPhone.

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for the update. Looking forward to it.