# Android: How to prevent video into full screen in WebView?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-fullscreen

Currently, we are creating an Android TV app, in this app, we use WebView to host a web page, there are a `<video>` tag in this web page, but when we click the play button, the video will go into fullscreen mode automatically.

We tried the following trick to prevent video into fullscreen, still can't prevent video into fullscreen mode.
[Can I avoid the native fullscreen video player with HTML5 on iPhone or android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054560/can-i-avoid-the-native-fullscreen-video-player-with-html5-on-iphone-or-android)

Anyone have experience to prevent video into fullscreen?

Comment: can you show me the webView code? may be i can do a favor

Comment: @ZhangXiang thanks man, we already changed the implementation with native VideoView, if you have any experience for this issue, please share it in comments.