# HTML5 video not working on iphone with react jsx

Tags: html, reactjs, video, jsx

I have a react application where i am using html5 video tag to show a cover video. It works on ipad, android and all the major browsers but on iphone it just shows a glimpse of a play button which if clicked shows a full page video.

```
class FrontPage extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.authorize = [''];
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <video controls="true" style={BGstyle} preload="yes" autoPlay muted loop width="100%" height="auto">
          <source src="/images/film.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
          Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
        <Ladder/>
        <SignUp/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
var BGstyle = {
  position: "absolute",
  zIndex:999,
  right:0,
  bottom:0,
  minWidth:'100%',
  width: 'auto',
  backgroundSize:"cover"
}

export default FrontPage;
```

you can see it on www.viogto.dk

Comment: I figured out it's a css error, if i delete all the css it works on iphone. How do i make a cover video work on iphone?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**For iOS 10+**

Try the `playsinline` attribute.
But in camel case for react :

```
<video playsInline>
```

Source - [New `video` Policies for iOS](https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/)

**In iOS 8 and iOS 9**

> Short answer: use [iphone-inline-video](https://github.com/bfred-it/iphone-inline-video), it enables inline playback and syncs the audio.
>
> Source - https://stackoverflow.com/a/36348909/3337722