# Zooming in on fullscreen video css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to zoom in on a video while in fullscreen portrait mode on a mobile device. Basically, I want to make the video content cover the device height while displaying the overflowing content outside of the viewport. I want the overflowing content to be visible when horizontally scrolled to. The problem is that i dont know how to adjust the viewport without the fullscreen mode adapting and I can't seem to find

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think you could do this with html5 video player. You might be able to do this with flash, but yuck...

Comment: I don't think you could do anything on fullscreen mode. I would play it on the web page (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054560/can-i-avoid-the-native-fullscreen-video-player-with-html5-on-iphone-or-android) and use css to zoom (transform: scale(2))