# disable fullscreen mode on html video on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I'm developing simple web application with video on one of the pages, but I don't want this video to open fullscreen mode on mobile devices.
I've tried to disable controls, but it still not works on mobiles.
Is there any option to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I avoid the native fullscreen video player with HTML5 on iPhone or android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054560/can-i-avoid-the-native-fullscreen-video-player-with-html5-on-iphone-or-android)

Comment: @imvain2 yeah. thank you

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use this code for mobile browsers:

```
<video autoplay loop muted controls webkit-playsinline playsinline>
    <source src="file.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Using `webkit-playsinline` and `playsinline` make Mobile browsers play the video right where it is instead of the default, which is to open it up full-screen while it plays.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It waws a solution

Comment: In Samsung native browser it will show video assistance control to make full screen in mobile. Even with playsinline.